# Unable to install vlc and mplayer after update on fedora 18

Tags: linux, fedora, vlc-media-player, mplayer

I just updated fedora 18 using

```
# yum update
```

Then if I try

```
# rpm -ivh http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-stable.noarch.rpm
```

I get,

```
Retrieving http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-stable.noarch.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.0K5pWw: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 172ff33d: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
system-release >= 19 is needed by rpmfusion-free-release-19-1.noarch
```

So I tried installing vlc from development version,

```
# rpm -ivh http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-rawhide.noarch.rpm
```

I get,

```
Retrieving http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-rawhide.noarch.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.WZC0gw: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 6446d859: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
system-release >= 21 is needed by rpmfusion-free-release-21-0.1.noarch
```

There's no system release after 20. What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that you installed a RPM Fusion **19** repository on a Fedora **18** system: You should either [upgrade](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Upgrading) (not update) the system or use the old (and unmaintained) RPM Fusion repository i.e.

```
yum install --nogpgcheck http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-18.noarch.rpm
```